# How to append a tag without the "/" added to the subsequent tags?

Tags: jquery

```
for(var s=0;s<selectedAll.length;s++) {
    var o=$(items[s]).attr('id');
    var val2="<DriverId='"+o+"' \/>";
    $("#result Params Drivers").append(val2);
}
```

I want O/p like:

```
<Drivers> 
<Driver id='1' /> 
<Driver id='2' /> 
<Driver id='3' />  
</Drivers>
```

But what ia m getting is,

```
<drivers>
<driverid='33813'>
<driverid='33812'>
</driverid='33812'>
</driverid='33813'>
</drivers>
```

How to get the requirement done...

Comment: *"But what ia m getting is,..."* No, you're not, as that's invalid HTML. Since you're doing this with the DOM, not strings, you're clearly not getting that. What makes you think you are?

Comment: Did you mean to have a space between `driver` and `id`? On the 3rd line of the pasted code, you don't have one...

Comment: no need to escape `/`

Comment: I really don't understand what you expect when using: ` var val2="<DriverId='"+o+"' \/>";`

Answer (score 0):

You need to build your tag properly: no uppercase, no escaping, like this:

```
var val2="<driver id="+o+">";
```

jQuery will handle quoting the attribute value, no need to wrap it in code (cleaner and more readable).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 for(var s=0;s<selectedAll.length;s++) {
        var o=$(items[s]).attr('id');
        var val2="<Driver Id='"+o+"' />";
        $("#result Params Drivers").append(val2);
    }
```